# ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested - POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a select with record history within 30 days, where the values column gets a count, I just wish it would add the values returned for each day.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    date_update AS Time,
    SUM(COUNT(values)) as "Value"
FROM
    tb_get_metrics
WHERE
    data_update >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
GROUP BY Time
ORDER BY Time
```

**Example OUTPUT:**

```
       Time                      Value
2019-10-14 09:46:54.789772        30
2019-10-15 09:46:54.789772        50
2019-10-16 09:46:54.789772        70
```

**SELECT * FROM tb_get_metrics**

```
  date_update(TimeStamp)        value(String)
2019-10-14 09:46:54.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:55.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:56.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:57.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:58.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:59.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:47:00.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:01.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:02.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:03.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:04.789772        apple
2019-10-14 09:46:05.789772        apple
2019-10-15 09:46:03.789772        potato
2019-10-15 09:46:04.789772        potato
2019-10-15 09:46:05.789772        potato
...
```

Comment: why do you need to `COUNT("values")`?

Comment: Because the values are strings, I want to count how many there are on that day

Comment: could you update the post with what `SELECT * FROM tb_get_metrics` would look like?

Comment: Remove the `sum` around the `count`.

Comment: ok, done, check please!! @richyen

Comment: The `SUM()` seems just redundant

Comment: The sum is the problem, as the error says, you can't nest aggregate problems.

Comment: Without the sum that generates a split output, for example 2 outputs for the same day

Comment: I would just like one out for each day with full value

Comment: Why do you want the timestamps in the results? Don't you want just the date?

Comment: I used date and time because of what I'm plotting the values in grafana @forpas

Comment: @klin solution solved the problem, thank you guys !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *round* the times to dates:

```
SELECT
    date_update::date AS "Date",
    COUNT(values) as "Value"
FROM
    tb_get_metrics
WHERE
    data_update >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
GROUP BY Time
ORDER BY Time
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the date part only from each timestamp to group by:

```
SELECT
    date_update::date AS Time,
    COUNT(values) AS "Value"
FROM tb_get_metrics
WHERE date_update >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
GROUP BY Time
ORDER BY Time
```

Comment: Thank you friend, your solution is functional !!

Answer (score 1):

By truncating the times off the timestamps, you can focus only on the date, which is what your `WHERE` clause seeks to do:

```
postgres=# SELECT
    date_update::date AS "Date",
    COUNT(values) as "Count"
FROM
    tb_get_metrics
WHERE
    date_update::date >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
GROUP BY "Date"           
ORDER BY "Date";
    Date    | Count 
------------+-------
 2019-10-14 |    24
 2019-10-15 |     6
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Perfect friend thank you so much for your effort to solve the problem !!